# How to stick the content of different divs together as if they form one paragraph?

Tags: css

My website contains a column with a list in it. I would like to start every single item with a @-sign instead of a bullet and stick the textual content of the `div`s in that item together. I copied the full code of my website underneath ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xrfpLuk/4/)):

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.item-list {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 230px;
}
.item-list li {
  list-style: inside none"@";
}
.field-name-field-plaats {
  display: inline;
}
.field-items {
  display: inline-block;
}
.field-name-field-aantal::before {
  content: " (";
}
.field-name-field-aantal::after {
  content: "x)";
}
.field-name-field-aantal {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="entity entity-field-collection-item field-collection-item-field-plaats-en-aantal clearfix">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="field field-name-field-plaats field-type-text field-label-hidden">
            <div class="field-items">
              <div class="field-item even">Blandit cogo dolor exerci ille luctus neo olim suscipit veli</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field field-name-field-aantal field-type-number-integer field-label-hidden">
            <div class="field-items">
              <div class="field-item even">1.362</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="entity entity-field-collection-item field-collection-item-field-plaats-en-aantal clearfix">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="field field-name-field-plaats field-type-text field-label-hidden">
            <div class="field-items">
              <div class="field-item even">Augue humo in interdico persto ymo. Abbas eligo neque nibh.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field field-name-field-aantal field-type-number-integer field-label-hidden">
            <div class="field-items">
              <div class="field-item even">5.487</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: Actual list]

This is not precisely the result that I want. Ideally, I would like to achieve something like this:

[image: Desired list]

Unfortunately, Paint doesn't deliver the correct CSS code... ;) I tried to play around with `white-space: nowrap`, but of course, that results in a single line of text, which is not what I want. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ul li *: display: inline !important;`

This should make everthing *inside* the `li`s  inline elements

EDIT/ADDITION:

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gk3nwdq4/2/

I also changed the CSS for the list-items in that to make the"@" be left of the text:

```
.item-list li {
  list-style: "@";
  margin: 5px 3px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: in fact I derived that from the OP's code, which was `list-style: inside none"@";` - it works on Firefox at least...

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.item-list {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 230px;
}
.item-list li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.item-list li:before {
  content: '@';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.field-name-field-plaats {
  display: inline;
}
.field-items {
  display: inline-block;
}
.field-name-field-aantal::before {
  content: " (";
}
.field-name-field-aantal::after {
  content: "x)";
}
.field-name-field-aantal {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-list">
  <ul>
<li>
  <div class="entity entity-field-collection-item field-collection-item-field-plaats-en-aantal clearfix">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="field field-name-field-plaats field-type-text field-label-hidden">
        <div class="field-items">
          <div class="field-item even">Blandit cogo dolor exerci ille luctus neo olim suscipit veli</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field field-name-field-aantal field-type-number-integer field-label-hidden">
        <div class="field-items">
          <div class="field-item even">1.362</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="entity entity-field-collection-item field-collection-item-field-plaats-en-aantal clearfix">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="field field-name-field-plaats field-type-text field-label-hidden">
        <div class="field-items">
          <div class="field-item even">Augue humo in interdico persto ymo. Abbas eligo neque nibh.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field field-name-field-aantal field-type-number-integer field-label-hidden">
        <div class="field-items">
          <div class="field-item even">5.487</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.item-list li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 5px 3px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.item-list li:before{
  content:'@';
  margin-left:-25px;
  margin-right:6px;
}
```